# Indexing JSON Commands with a tree model of GTK+ GUI

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, gtk, trie

I have an idea that I want to implement but have no idea on how to proceed or an algorithm for that.

1. I have a json file that has a list of strings as commands
2. In the Client Side of the GUI, I use GTK+ tree model https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/iface.TreeModel.html
3. The problem is I have 20K of Commands that I need to search of
4. My idea is to implement a trie of the json commands list, but have no idea on how to approach that, what would be the key ? how to populate the tree model from the result of the trie ?